# How to upload multiple PDF files using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to upload multiple pdf files using php, but the [following code](https://codepen.io/Minanabil/pen/MdYgXY) is allowing to upload only img, png....I have added application/pdf but only one PDF file is being uploaded, not multiple. I want to upload multiple PDF files same as this code is uploading  accepted files, selecting one by one and all at once.

Can you please help me to upload multiple pdf files and upload in sql?

Thank you.

```
<div>
        <label style="font-size: 14px;">
            <span style='color:navy;font-weight:bold'>Attachment Instructions :</span>
        </label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Allowed only files with extension (jpg, png, gif)
            </li>
            <li>
                Maximum number of allowed files 10 with 300 KB for each
            </li>
            <li>
                you can select files from different folders
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--To give the control a modern look, I have applied a stylesheet in the parent span.-->
        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
            <span>Select Attachment</span>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
        </span>
        <output id="Filelist"></output>
    </div>




    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
      
        //To save an array of attachments
        var AttachmentArray = [];
        
        //counter for attachment array
        var arrCounter = 0;
        
        //to make sure the error message for number of files will be shown only one time.
        var filesCounterAlertStatus = false;
        
        //un ordered list to keep attachments thumbnails
        var ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ul.className = "thumb-Images";
        ul.id = "imgList";
        
        function init() {
          //add javascript handlers for the file upload event
          document
            .querySelector("#files")
            .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
        }
        
        //the handler for file upload event
        function handleFileSelect(e) {
          //to make sure the user select file/files
          if (!e.target.files) return;
        
          //To obtaine a File reference
          var files = e.target.files;
        
          // Loop through the FileList and then to render image files as thumbnails.
          for (var i = 0, f; (f = files[i]); i++) {
            //instantiate a FileReader object to read its contents into memory
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
        
            // Closure to capture the file information and apply validation.
            fileReader.onload = (function(readerEvt) {
              return function(e) {
                //Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
                ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt);
        
                //Render attachments thumbnails.
                RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt);
        
                //Fill the array of attachment
                FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt);
              };
            })(f);
        
            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            // readAsDataURL: The result property will contain the file/blob's data encoded as a data URL.
            // More info about Data URI scheme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
          }
          document
            .getElementById("files")
            .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
        }
        
        //To remove attachment once user click on x button
        jQuery(function($) {
          $("div").on("click", ".img-wrap .close", function() {
            var id = $(this)
              .closest(".img-wrap")
              .find("img")
              .data("id");
        
            //to remove the deleted item from array
            var elementPos = AttachmentArray.map(function(x) {
              return x.FileName;
            }).indexOf(id);
            if (elementPos !== -1) {
              AttachmentArray.splice(elementPos, 1);
            }
        
            //to remove image tag
            $(this)
              .parent()
              .find("img")
              .not()
              .remove();
        
            //to remove div tag that contain the image
            $(this)
              .parent()
              .find("div")
              .not()
              .remove();
        
            //to remove div tag that contain caption name
            $(this)
              .parent()
              .parent()
              .find("div")
              .not()
              .remove();
        
            //to remove li tag
            var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#imgList li");
            for (var i = 0; (li = lis[i]); i++) {
              if (li.innerHTML == "") {
                li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
              }
            }
          });
        });
        
        //Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
        function ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt) {
          //To check file type according to upload conditions
          if (CheckFileType(readerEvt.type) == false) {
            alert(
              "The file (" +
                readerEvt.name +
                ") does not match the upload conditions, You can only upload jpg/png/gif files"
            );
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
          }
        
          //To check file Size according to upload conditions
          if (CheckFileSize(readerEvt.size) == false) {
            alert(
              "The file (" +
                readerEvt.name +
                ") does not match the upload conditions, The maximum file size for uploads should not exceed 300 KB"
            );
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
          }
        
          //To check files count according to upload conditions
          if (CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) == false) {
            if (!filesCounterAlertStatus) {
              filesCounterAlertStatus = true;
              alert(
                "You have added more than 10 files. According to upload conditions you can upload 10 files maximum"
              );
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
          }
        }
        
        //To check file type according to upload conditions
        function CheckFileType(fileType) {
          if (fileType == "image/jpeg") {
            return true;
          } else if (fileType == "image/png") {
            return true;
          } else if (fileType == "image/gif") {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
        
        //To check file Size according to upload conditions
        function CheckFileSize(fileSize) {
          if (fileSize < 300000) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
        
        //To check files count according to upload conditions
        function CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) {
          //Since AttachmentArray.length return the next available index in the array,
          //I have used the loop to get the real length
          var len = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < AttachmentArray.length; i++) {
            if (AttachmentArray[i] !== undefined) {
              len++;
            }
          }
          //To check the length does not exceed 10 files maximum
          if (len > 9) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
        
        //Render attachments thumbnails.
        function RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          ul.appendChild(li);
          li.innerHTML = [
            '<div class="img-wrap"> <span class="close">&times;</span>' +
              '<img class="thumb" src="',
            e.target.result,
            '" title="',
            escape(readerEvt.name),
            '" data-id="',
            readerEvt.name,
            '"/>' + "</div>"
          ].join("");
        
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.className = "FileNameCaptionStyle";
          li.appendChild(div);
          div.innerHTML = [readerEvt.name].join("");
          document.getElementById("Filelist").insertBefore(ul, null);
        }
        
        //Fill the array of attachment
        function FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt) {
          AttachmentArray[arrCounter] = {
            AttachmentType: 1,
            ObjectType: 1,
            FileName: readerEvt.name,
            FileDescription: "Attachment",
            NoteText: "",
            MimeType: readerEvt.type,
            Content: e.target.result.split("base64,")[1],
            FileSizeInBytes: readerEvt.size
          };
          arrCounter = arrCounter + 1;
        }
```

Comment: `accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"` will not allow PDFs. You must include `.pdf` or `application/pdf`. Also, your `CheckFileType()` function is preventing PDFs from being uploaded.